# event sourcing event only referencer other aggregateRoot id how to update read model

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

ask for advice! If there are only other aggregate root ids in the event, how to deal with it when updating the read model. For example, if an order aggregate root has a creator id in the main order and a product ID in the items , then the creation event will only have the creator id and product id. Then in the event When updating the reading model, should I go to other reading models to check the relevant creator name and product description? Or should these names be used as attributes of the aggregate root or entity from the beginning? Or design the id and name directly as a value object ?

i try to use value object has id

Answer (score 0):

The ID of the aggregate who issued the event should also be included in the event. Meaning "the aggregate that owns the event".

There is no problem for the projections on the read side to query other projections for data. The alternative is to include the data, if possible, in the event (or previously related events), so that the event need to cross-query is limited.